# Setting up VPN with wired and wireless connection

Tags: linux, debian, vpn, wifi, wpa

I have a VPN working for the wired connection but it doesn't seem to work for the wireless connection.

I'm trying to get a VPN set up with both a wired and wireless connection.  So to do so, after the connection is brought up, img calling `pon settings`.  However, for a reason that I can't figure out, it works for the wired connection (eth0) but not for the wireless connection (wlan0).  Here is `/etc/network/interfaces/`

```
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

 iface eth0 inet dhcp
      post-up pon settings
      pre-down poff

 allow-hotplug wlan0
 iface wlan0 inet manual
      wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
      pre-down poff
      post-up pon settings

 iface default inet dhcp

 iface ppp0 inet ppp
      provider settings
```

I'm guessing there is something wrong with `iface wlan0 inet manual`.  I tried replacing it with `auto iface wlan0 inet` and `iface wlan0 inet dhcp` (like for the wired one) but they did't work.

Comment: How does your `wlan0` interface get an IP address if you're not using DHCP?

Comment: good question.  I'm not quite sure.  It does get one though.  Perhaps another line in the `interfaces` file is doing it or could there be another thing doing it?  Wicd nor NM is installed.